# if文のもっと短い書き方を教えて頂きたいです

Tags: objective-c

初心者で質問の内容が足りないかもしれません。
`if`文において、変数等を使って以下のコードをもう少し短く書く方法は御座いますでしょうか？
ご教授のほど宜しくお願い致します。

内容としましては、別クラスから呼び出したメソッドのTitleが「空っぽ」＆「nil」でない場合のif文です。宜しくお願い致します。

```
if (![[Data ValueWithKey:InformationTitle] isEqual:@""] &&
    ![[Data ValueWithKey:InformationTitle] isEqual:nil]) {}
```

Comment: 質問文では _「空っぽ」かつ「nil」でない場合_ ですが、コードでは _「空っぽ」_ **でない** _かつ「nil」でない場合_ が表現されています。本当の趣旨はどちらですか

Comment: もし、コードのほうが趣旨に沿う場合、ただ1文字以上の文字列であればよく、答えは `if ([Data ValueWithKey: InformationTitle].length > 0) {}` のようになってしまいます

Comment: ご返答頂き有難うございます。空であり、そしてnilでもある。という条件で御座います！この説明で宜しいでしょうか？誰が見てもわかりやすいように、カラとヌルをあえて記載する必要性を要求されているかと思います

Comment: 後から読む方が混乱するので、質問文のコードを直したほうがいいですね

Comment: どのようにコードを直す必要がありますでしょうか？ご教授のほどお願い致します。

Comment: 条件の一つ目が `![[Data ValueWithKey:InformationTitle] isEqual:@""]` ですが、こちらには否定の `!` は不要です

Comment: 空っぽ」かつ「nil」では無いというソースの為、！は必要かと存じますが如何でしょうか。

Comment: それは、空っぽであってもいけないし、`nil`であってもいけない、という意味ですか？

Comment: はい、左様で御座います。色々とご教授頂き有難うございます。しかしながら、下記教えて頂きました内容では解決しませんでした。何か良い方法をご教授頂けますと幸いで御座います。if ((emptyString != nil) && (emptyString.length == 0))では上手く判定してくれませんでした。

Comment: 前述したように、文字列が1文字以上か判定するだけです。空白を文字と認識したくない場合は文字数判定前に除去してください

Comment: 承知いたしました。しかしながら、先方がどうしても、nilとカラの２つを入れてほしいとの事で困っております。どうにか良い方法ございますでしょうか？

Comment: 申し訳ございません。空白を文字と認識したくない場合は文字数判定前に除去してください。の意味がイマイチ理解できません。ソース頂けますと幸いで御座います。

Comment: 最初の回答者に意図が異なっていたことをコメントしてください。このやりとりを見れば正しいコードに直してくれると思います。最初の回答者は空文字判定だと勘違いしているだけです

Comment: 承知致しました。有難うございました。もう諦めます。

Comment: 無事に解決致しました。初心者で訳のわからない質問にお答え頂き有難うございました！大変助かりました！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こんな感じでしょうか？

```
emptyString = [Data ValueWithKey:InformationTitle];
if ((emptyString != nil) && (emptyString.length == 0))
{
    // do something
} //end if value is ""
```

もっと短く書くなら

```
emptyString = [Data ValueWithKey:InformationTitle];
if (!emptyString && (emptyString.length == 0))
{
    // do something
} //end if value is ""
```

という書き方も出来ると思います。

余談ですが、

- クラス名は大文字から
- 変数名は小文字から

書き始めるのが良いと思いますので、Dataという変数名は避けた方がいいと思います。

追記
質問のコメントを拝見して、回答の趣旨が間違っていることに気がつきました。
上のコードはタイトルが「空っぽ」かつ「nilでない」事を判別するコードになります。
「空っぽ」でも「nil」でもない事を判別するためには以下のコードになります。

```
emptyString = [Data ValueWithKey:InformationTitle];
if ((emptyString != nil) && (emptyString.length > 0))
{
    // do something
} //end if value is not empty
```

再追記
if文の中に入ってくれないという事で、デバッグ用に冗長化したコードを記述してみます。
以下をステップ実行して、BOOL型の2つの変数にそれぞれYES(true)が代入されるかを確認してみてください。

```
NSString *title = [Data ValueWithKey:InformationTitle];
BOOL isNotNil = title ? YES : NO;
BOOL isNotEmpty = (title.length > 0) ? YES : NO;
if (isNotNil && isNotEmpty)
{
     // do something
} // end if title is there
```

Comment: ご教授頂き有難うございます！大変勉強になりました。また、クラス名は大文字、変数名は小文字、変数名につきましても気をつけます！有難うございました！大変助かりました！

Comment: 質問の意図を誤解しており、質問者の問題が解決していないそうです。回答を改善できますか？

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。追記しました。

Comment: 追記ありがとうございました。上記でも上手く動かないようで御座いました。emptyStringは、エラーとなるため、NSString *emptyStringに変更したのですが、これが原因でしょうか。(emptyString != nil) のみにしても判定せず、(emptyString.length > 0 )のみにしても判定しませんでした。もし解決方法等御座いましたら、ご教授のほどお願い致します。

Comment: 質問の意図を勘違いして申し訳ありませんでした。判定しないとはどういう状況でしょうか？

Comment: 大変失礼致しました。上記ソースで無事に解決致しました。何度もご確認頂き大変ご迷惑をお掛け致しました。また、色々とご教授頂き有難うございました。こちらでクローズさせて頂きます。

Answer (score 0):

すでに解決してるのでこれは無視してもらってもいいです。

```
NSString *title = [Data ValueWithKey:InformationTitle];
if( title.length != 0 ) {
    //
}
```

これでいいです。

解説:
Objective-Cでは nilへのメッセージパッシングは0を返します。（例外を除きます）
ですので、もしtitleがnilであれば title.length は0を返すので条件は偽となります。
titleがnilでなければ通常の文字列の長さが返ってきますので空文字列以外は真となります。
また、lengthの戻り値の型はNSUIntegerですのでマイナスになることは考慮しなくてよいです。

nilへのメッセージパッシングの戻り値の例外:
ざっくりと言うと「レジスタに入りきらない大きさの構造体に類するものを返すメソッドの場合は戻り値が不定となる。」です。
それ以外は必ず0が返ります。

気になること：

```
[Data ValueWithKey:InformationTitle]
```

これが本当にNSStringかチェックしてないけど大丈夫？